# How could I match time string with python re module?

Tags: python, regex, python-re

I would like to match the time string python with python re module. My code is like this:

```
import re
def match_time(el):
    year = '(?:19|20)[0-9]{2}'
    month = '(?:0?[1-9]|1|[0-2])'
    day = '(?:0?|[1-9]|[1-2][0-9]|3[0-1])'
    hour = '(?:[0-1]?[0-9]|2[0-4])'
    minute = '(?:[0-5]?[0-9])'
    second = '(?:[0-5]?[0-9])'
    sep = '\s?'

    date_pattern = '{year}[/-]{month}[/-]{day}'.format(year=year, month=month, day=day)
    time_pattern = '(?:{sep}{hour}:{minute}:{second})?'.format(sep=sep, hour=hour, minute=minute, second=second)

    p = date_pattern + time_pattern

    m = re.findall(p, el)
    return m

el = '2019/3/23 0:11:01 fxxxxxff fff'

m = match_time(el)
print(m)
```

The output of this is `2019/3/`. What error it is with my code please ? I hope the function can match sentences like both `2019/3/23 0:11:01 fxxxxx ffff` and `2019/3/23 fffdddd dddwww`, so I added a `?` after the `time_pattern`, but the output is weird. How could I make it work please ?

Answer (score 2):

In my work, I like to almost always assume Regex is greedy in searching for options. When you give it `0?` as the first option, it allows for an empty string (is this what you want? I assume not), and it will select that is the valid solution. So reordering your regex will work.

```
year = '(?:19|20)[0-9]{2}'
month = '(?:0?[1-9]|1[0-2])'
day = '(?:[1-2][0-9]|3[0-1]|0?[1-9])'
hour = '(?:[0-1]?[0-9]|2[0-4])'
minute = '(?:[0-5]?[0-9])'
second = '(?:[0-5]?[0-9])'
sep = '\s?'
```

This captures your desired output, though I doubt it is the most efficient method, it varies the least from your own work.

Comment: I found a bug in OP's month regex. Correct value should be `month = '(?:0?[1-9]|1[0-2])'` . Also, your solution works great!

Comment: @AnkurSaxena There really is one, it's really just to be able to use `|` in an enclosed setting

Comment: @AnkurSaxena Thanks for telling me this !!! Would you please add a few lines about what is the most efficient way you mentioned in the answer ?